# Troubles predicting fixed effects from a hierarchical GAM in mgcv

Tags: r, hierarchical-data, mixed-models, gam, mgcv

I have been fitting different hierarchical GAMs (hereafter: HGAM) using `mgcv` in R. I can extract and plot their predictions for their random effects without problems. Conversely, extracting and plotting their predictions for their fixed effects only works for some models, and I don't know why.

Here is a practical example, which refers to the color spectra of flowers from two species (`Taxon`) sampled at various localities (also discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/403772/different-ways-of-modelling-interactions-between-continuous-and-categorical-pred)):

```
rm(list=ls()) # wipe R's memory clean
library(pacman) # load packages, installing them from CRAN if needed
p_load(RCurl) # allows accessing data from URL
ss <- read.delim(text=getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/marcoplebani85/datasets/master/flower_color_spectra.txt"))
head(ss)
ss$density <- ifelse(ss$density<0, 0, ss$density) # set spurious negative reflectance values to zero
ss$clr <- ifelse(ss$Taxon=="SpeciesB", "red", "black")
ss <- with(ss, ss[order(Locality, wl), ])
```

These are the mean color spectra at the population level for the two species (rolling means were used):

[image]

*Each color refers to a different species. Each line refers to a different locality.*

The following model is a HGAM of type G according to [Pedersen et al.'s classification (2019)](https://peerj.com/articles/6876/) and it does not give any issues:

```
gam_G1 <- bam(density ~ Taxon # main effect
        + s(wl, by = Taxon, k = 20) # interaction
        + s(Locality, bs="re"), # "re" is short for "random effect"
        data = ss, method = 'REML',
        family="quasipoisson"
        )
# gam.check(gam_G1)
# k.check(gam_G1)   
# MuMIn::AICc(gam_G1)
# gratia::draw(gam_G1)
# plot(gam_G1, pages=1)

# use gam_G1 to predict wl by Locality

# dataset of predictor values to estimate response values for:    
nn <- unique(ss[, c("wl", "Taxon", "Locality", "clr")])
# predict:
pred <- predict(object= gam_G1, newdata=nn, type="response", se.fit=T)
nn$fit <- pred$fit
nn$se <- pred$se.fit

# use gam_G1 to predict wl by Taxon
    
# dataset of predictor values to estimate response values for:
nn <- unique(ss[, c("wl", 
                "Taxon", 
                "Locality",
                "clr")])
nn$Locality=0 # turns random effect off
# after https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/131106/214127

# predict:
pred <- predict(object = gam_G1, 
                type="response", 
                newdata=nn, 
                se.fit=T)
nn$fit <- pred$fit
nn$se <- pred$se.fit
```

R warns me that `factor levels 0 not in original fit`, but it executes the task without issues:

[image]

*Left panel: `gam_G1` predictions at the `Locality` level. Right panel: `gam_G1` predictions for the fixed effects.*

**Troublesome models**

The following model is a HGAM of type "GI" *sensu* [Pedersen et al. (2019)](https://peerj.com/articles/6876/). It produces more accurate predictions at the `Locality` level, but I can only get `NA` as predictions at the level of fixed effects:

```
# GI: models with a global smoother for all observations, 
# plus group-level smoothers, the wiggliness of which is estimated individually 
start_time <- Sys.time()
gam_GI1 <- bam(density ~ Taxon # main effect
        + s(wl, by = Taxon, k = 20) # interaction
        + s(wl, by = Locality, bs="tp", m=1)
        # "tp" is short for "thin plate [regression spline]"
        + s(Locality, bs="re"),
        family="quasipoisson",
        data = ss, method = 'REML'
        )
end_time <- Sys.time()
end_time - start_time # it took ~2.2 minutes on my computer
# gam.check(gam_GI1)
# k.check(gam_GI1)
# MuMIn::AICc(gam_GI1)
```

Attempt at drawing predictions for the fixed effects (`Taxon` and `wl`) according to `gam_GI1`:

```
# dataset of predictor values to estimate response values for:
nn <- unique(ss[, c("wl", 
                "Taxon", 
                "Locality",
                "clr")])
nn$Locality=0 # turns random effect off
# after https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/131106/214127

# predict:
pred <- predict(object = gam_GI1, 
                type="response", 
                # exclude="c(Locality)", 
                # # this should turn random effect off
                # # (doesn't work for me)
                newdata=nn, 
                se.fit=T)
nn$fit <- pred$fit
nn$se <- pred$se.fit
head(nn)
#       wl    Taxon Locality clr fit se
# 1 298.34 SpeciesB        0 red  NA NA
# 2 305.82 SpeciesB        0 red  NA NA
# 3 313.27 SpeciesB        0 red  NA NA
# 4 320.72 SpeciesB        0 red  NA NA
# 5 328.15 SpeciesB        0 red  NA NA
# 6 335.57 SpeciesB        0 red  NA NA
```

[image]

*Left panel: `gam_GI1` predictions at the `Locality` level. Right panel (blank): `gam_GI1` predictions for the fixed effects.*

The following model, which includes a global smoother for all observations, plus group-level smoothers, all with the same "wiggliness", doesn't provide fixed-effect predictions either:

```
gam_GS1 <- bam(density ~ Taxon # main effect
        + s(wl, by = Taxon, k = 20) # interaction
        + s(wl, by = Locality, bs="fs", m=1),
        # "fs" is short for "factor-smoother [interaction]"
        family="quasipoisson",
        data = ss, method = 'REML'
        )
```

**Why don't `gam_GI1` and `gam_GS1` produce predictions for their fixed effects, and how can I obtain them?**

---

*The models can take a few minutes to run. To save time, their output can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/marcoplebani85/plotting_HGAM/raw/main/troublesome_HGAMs.RData) as an RData file. My R scripts (which include the code for plotting the figures) are available [here](https://github.com/marcoplebani85/plotting_HGAM/tree/main).*

Comment: This might be worth looking into: https://m-clark.github.io/gammit/reference/predict_gamm.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are conflating several things here; The `by` trick to turn off random effects only works for `bs = "re"` smooths. `Locality` is a factor (otherwise your random effect isn't a random intercept) and setting it to `0` is creating a new level (although it could be creating an NA as `0` isn't among the original levels.

If what you want to do is turn off anything to do with `Locality`, you should use `exclude`; however you have the invocation wrong. The reason why it's not working is because you are creating a character vector with a single element `"c(Locality)"`. This fails for obvious reasons once you realize that `c(Locality)` doesn't related to anything in your model. What you need to provide here is a vector of smooth names *as printed by `summary()`*. For example, to exclude the smooth `s(Locality, bs = "re")`, {mgcv} knows this as `s(Locality)`, so you would use `exclude = "s(Locality)"`.

In your case, it is tedious to type out all the `"s(wl):LocalityLevelX"` labels for each smooth. As you have only two taxa, it would be easier to use the complimentary argument `terms`, where you list smooth labels that you want to *include* in the model. So you could do `terms = c("s(wl):TaxonSpeciesB", "s(wl):TaxonSpeciesC")` or whatever `summary()` displays for these smooths.

You also need to include the `Taxon` term in `terms`, which I think needs to be:

```r
terms = c("TaxonSpeciesB", TaxonSpeciesC", 
          "s(wl):TaxonSpeciesB", "s(wl):TaxonSpeciesC")
```

If you install and load my {gratia} package, you can use `smooths(gam_GI1)` to list all the smooth labels as far as {mgcv} knows them.

The `by` trick works like this:

```r
gam(y ~ x + s(z) + s(id, bs = "re", by = dummy)
```

where `dummy` is set to a *numeric* value `1` when fitting and to `0` when you are predicting. As this is a *numeric* by variable you are multiplying the smooth by `dummy` and hence why setting it to `0` excludes the term. The reason why your code isn't working is because you really want separate smooths for `wl` for each `Locality`; `Locality` is an actual variable of interest in your data/model, not a dummy variable we create to achieve the aim of excluding a term from the model.

Hopefully now you can see why `exclude` and `terms` are much better solutions than this `dummy` trick.

FYI, in `bs = "tp"`, the `"tp"` doesn't mean tensor product smooth. It mean thin plate regression spline (TPRS). You only get tensor product smooths through `te()`, `t2()`, or `ti()` terms.

Comment: Thank you! `terms` worked like a charm. The result looks the same regardless of whether `terms = c("s(wl):TaxonSpeciesA", "s(wl):TaxonSpeciesB")` or `terms = c("TaxonSpeciesA", "TaxonSpeciesB", "s(wl):TaxonSpeciesA", "s(wl):TaxonSpeciesB")` are used. Thanks also for clarifying the meaning of `"tp"`.

Comment: Ah, so it's including the all the parametric terms automatically then.